# Conditional if statement for a particular WP page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Woo Commerce plugin and I want to display extra text for a specific product page.
The product ID seen in my body is:
single single-product postid-2624

So I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
<?php
function ip_more_content() {
    if ( is_single('2624'); ) {
        echo 'show something';
    }
    else {
       echo '';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' , 'ip_more_content', 9 );
?>
```

How can I make WP do something based on a specific product id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' is running inside the loop, so you cab grab item id by simply using get_the_ID() function. So, edit your conditional like this:

```
if ( get_the_ID() == 2624 ) {
```

And it should work it out.

Comment: Thanks a million, Codeartist!